# How to use default cluster-issuer with SAS Viya

Tags: kubernetes, sas, kustomize

I have a Kubernetes cluster with cert-manager and a cluster-issuer installed.

Is there a way to get SAS Viya to use this default cluster-issuer, instead of the provided `sas-viya-issuer` issuer?

When I run a `kubectl describe` on one of the ingress definitions created as part of my SAS Viya deployment, this is what I get back

```
Annotations: cert-manager.io/issuer: sas-viya-issuer
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
             nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
```

But I would rather use my own cluster-issuer.

I've tried adding this to my kustomize transformers block

```
path: /metadata/annotations/cert-manager.io~1cluster-issuer
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

### UPDATE

I've added the following block to my `transformers` section

```
- site-config/security/ingress-annotation-transformer.yaml
```

```
---
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PatchTransformer
metadata:
  name: sas-cert-manager-ingress-annotation-transformer
patch: |-
  - op: add
    path: /metadata/annotations/cert-manager.io~1issuer
    value: default-issuer
target:
  kind: Ingress
  name: .*
```

The `default-issuer` exists and I'm able to use it to create TLS protected endpoints via an ingress definition, however, this does not work with SAS Viya.

Comment: could you please share file or link of github repo or helm if you are using the same.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you asking how to use `kustomize` to patch your manifests to replace the value of the `cert-manager.io/issuer` annotation? Can you show us your `kustomization.yaml` in which you're trying to make these changes?

Comment: @larsks what I'm trying to do is to deploy SAS Viya with TLS enabled. 
I'm able to deploy the application alright, but it appears to be using the default issuer called sas-viya-issuer, which does not provide TLS when I attempt to access the application via an ingress controller. I've amended the original question.